# UICollectionView hitTest -> normal behavior

Tags: ios, uiview, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout, hittest

I overrode hitTest, and that works just fine. I want it to behave as if I hadn't overridden this method under certain conditions, and that's where the problem lies.

I'm using a subclassed `UICollectionView` to render cells over a `MKMapView` using a custom `UICollectionViewLayout` implementation. I needed to override `hitTest` in the `UICollectionView` subclass so that touch events can be passed to the mapView and it can be scrolled. That all works fine.

I have a toggle mechanism which animates between my `UICollectionViewLayout` (map) to a `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` (animate items on a map to a grid format). This works good too, but when I'm showing the flow layout, I want the user to be able to scroll the `UICollectionView` like a normal one (act as though hitTest isn't overridden). I can't figure out what to return in `hitTest` to have it's default behavior.

```
-(UIView*)hitTest:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
    if(self.tapThrough == YES){
        NSArray *indexPaths = [self indexPathsForVisibleItems];
        for(NSIndexPath *indexPath in indexPaths){
            UICollectionViewCell *cell = [self cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];
            if(CGRectContainsPoint(cell.frame, point)){
                return cell;
            }
        }
        return nil;
    } else {
        return ???
    }
}
```

I've tried returning a number of things. `self`, `self.superview`, etc... Nothing get it to behave normally (I cannot scroll the cells up and down).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the normal behaviour of your hit test:

```
return [super hitTest:point withEvent:event];
```

This will return what the hit test usually returns when it is not overridden.

Comment: You are correct. I had tried that, but at the same time I had implemented: - (BOOL)gestureRecognizerShouldBegin:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer{
    return NO;
}